# Close socket without waiting for send to succeeed - Winsock2 non-blocking TCP socket

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, winsock2

I am using a non-blocking socket via a socket library that wraps the Winsock2 API. The `WSAAsyncSelect()` function is used to have socket notifications sent to a window. (The application is single-threaded).

I am trying to achieve the following aim for an open client socket:

- Send a final message to the server
- Close the socket and destroy the window

I do not want to do a blocking wait for the server to `ACK` my last message, as this introduces another point of delay/failure to users of my code. It's not a vital message to my protocol, just a nice-to-have.

Currently, my code ends up calling Winsock2 `send()` to send the final message, and then calls `closesocket()`. However, my TCP flow (as viewed by Wireshark) then looks like:

```
// Calling send():
Me -> Host:  [PSH, ACK] 

// Calling closesocket():
Me -> Host:  [FIN, ACK] 

// Just after that:
Host -> Me:  [ACK]    
Host -> Me:  [ACK]
Host -> Me:  [ACK] Len=1380   // A response to my sent packet, that I don't care about
Me -> Host:  [RST, ACK]
Host -> Me:  [RST]
Host -> Me:  [PSH, ACK]  // Retransmission of that response
Me -> Host:  [RST]
```

So there are two RST requests sent by Windows.  I believe this is because the socket receives a message after sending `FIN` so it decides that `RST` is necessary, but then the host interprets that as a retransmission request.

If I change my code to wait a little bit before calling `closesocket`, then the trace looks very different: my end just sends `[FIN, ACK]` and the other end sends `[FIN, ACK]` back and there are no RSTs.

My question is: how can I tidily shut down my socket (i.e. avoid RST exchanges) without having to block?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; since this is a non-blocking socket, why would the final read need to be a blocking read?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I destroy the modal window that the socket notifications are going to, so it is not possible to do a non-blocking read

Comment: Ah.  Could you hide the window instead, and destroy it after the connection has been cleanly shut down?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Maybe, I'll investigate. My code is inside a DLL which is loaded into the process of code beyond my control, so having any non-modal window accepting messages relies in the third party having a sane message loop... and I'm wary of relying on that in general :) But thanks for the idea, it may be workable nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to do a blocking wait for the server to ACK my last message, as this introduces another point of delay/failure to users of my code. It's not a vital message to my protocol, just a nice-to-have.

I assume you're speaking of an application-level ACK. Unread data will provoke an RST to the sender if you close before it arrives. You have to decide about this. Either it is in the protocol or it isn't.

Comment: I'm talking about a TCP ACK. If there is network congestion then this could be slow in arriving and I don't want my UI to have to wait around if the network is slow, or goes down during this operation.

Comment: Are you saying the only options are, (a) wait for response packet before closing socket, or (b) close socket and have RSTs ?

Comment: Then I don't know what you're talking about. You can't 'do a blocking wait for the server to `ACK` my last message', or 'wait for a response packet' in any way. You don't have any API that does so. The API gives you zero visibility of `ACKs.` You can just send and close. RSTs are usually provoked by unread *application* data. Such as the one with `Len=1380` that you seem to have forgotten about.

Comment: OK. Then let's say I know the server will respond to my message but I don't want to wait for that.

Comment: Then you'll provoke RSTs. The cleanest way to handle this situation is really to shutdown the socket for output, read all the input until end of stream, then close. At both ends. Then you get no RSTs at all, but you get the read delay. Or else just put up with the resets, and what they cause at the peer.

Comment: This is the preferred way to shut down a socket, as it lets both parties perform graceful shutdowns on both ends.